# MySQL Select All Rows with Distinct Count Greater Than

Tags: mysql

I have a table `relationship` that looks like this:

```
relationshipId   userId   teamId
--------------   ------   ------
1                1234     999
2                5678     999
3                1234     888
4                1234     999
```

What I want to do is create a query that shows me every row where the userId, teamId combination is duplicated in the table.

I know I can find the duplicated rows and the number of times they are duplicated by using a query like `select userId, teamId, count(*) from relationship group by userId, teamId having count(*) > 1`

The above query would return:

```
userId   teamId  count
------   ------  -----
1234     999     2
```

What I want is a query that will show me the two rows that yielded the `count of 2` so that I can access the unique `relationshipIds`.

So, I'm looking for a result of:

```
relationshipId   userId   teamId
--------------   ------   ------
1                1234     999
4                1234     999
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is the step to identify which relation is duplicated.

To get the data you want, you need to use this result and link it to the same table to filter on the result.

Here is the query:

```
select a.*
from relationship as a
, (
    select userId
    , teamId
    from relationship
    group by userId
    , teamId
    having count(*) > 1
) as b
where a.userId = b.userId
and a.teamId = b.teamId
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks so much. Sorry I can't vote up but I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

While A.D.'s answer uses a subquery, you could also try a view:

`Create view relationship_view As
  Select relationshipID, userID, teamID, count() 
  from relationship 
  having count() > 1;`

Then just query off that view:
 
   `select * from relationship_view 
   group by userID, teamID;`

Comment: I think it is not correct since OP wants the distinct ids for all duplicates. Or you can use a GROUP_CONCAT aggregate function. But even in that case, I am not sure it will answer OP's question.

Comment: Looking back now I see what you mean and thanks for critiquing my answer.